# HTML best practice for multiple form submission options to php script

Tags: php, html

I've ended up in a situation where I'm going to have a list of entries held in a table, set of divs, or whatever.  Each entry will have multiple actions that can be performed on it - "Edit", "Delete", etc.

I'm relatively good at CSS/HTML from a UI point of view, but I'm still hazy on information management through forms.

I know I can have a hyperlink go to an address using GET notation (addr.com?id=17&act=edit), and I should be able to read the values using the PHP script GET'd to.  Is this a... intelligent? way to handle this situation though?

I wasn't sure if it was secure enough or if there was a common way to handle this situation.  Any light you can shed on a common way to handle this situation would be wonderful.

Comment: Where will your list of entries be coming from? Will you be editing/deleting those entries using the actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this frequently, and I almost always use a GET notation as you've described. It makes it very easy to separate action and the UID of the record to act upon.

```
e.g. /submit.php?action=edit&uid=17
```

We can then route through multiple actions in PHP rather simply:

```
<?php

$uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
switch ( $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
    case 'edit':
        $notice = editRecord ( $uid );
        break;

    case 'delete':
        sqlQuery("DELETE FROM `records` WHERE `uid` = '$uid' LIMIT 1");
        $notice = 'The record has been removed.';
        break;

    case 'rename':
        $newname = $_REQUEST['name'];
        sqlQuery("UPDATE `records` SET `name` = '$newname' WHERE `uid` = '$uid' LIMIT 1");
        $notice = 'The record has been renamed.';
        break;

    default:
}

?>
<h1>Admin Panel</h1>
<?php if ( isset( $notice ) ) echo $notice; ?>
```

We can also use POST to save edits, upload images, etc. when necessary.  Because we rely on the $_REQUEST superglobal variable, both $_GET and $_POST are fed into it so it works for both types of form submissions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't there's any problem using GET for these actions, as it is widely used. However, using [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) might actually be a little more secure (if you protect from [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) attacks etcetera...).

It all depends on how much security measures you need and how sensitive the data or actions in your application are. As long as you keep certain security principles in mind, you can use both GET and POST, even together.
For both GET and POST, it's always important to never trust the input and escape and filter, and attempt to prevent CSRF and other attacks.

I suggest you read some tutorials on the web and try to see for yourself what request method is the best option.